# Is there a way to query for distinct row records in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in Oracle where all fields are the same except for "Name":

```
Name, Age, Nickname, FavSport
A, 5, Jordan, Hockey
A, 6, Jordan, Hockey
B, 5, Jordan, Hockey
B, 6, Jordan, Hockey
```

Is there a way to execute a query such that I get "distinct records" based on all other fields besides a single field?

i.e. Sample Output

```
A, 5, Jordan, Hockey
A, 6, Jordan, Hockey
```

Or is there even a better way where I can get:

```
A-B, 5, Jordan, Hockey
A-B, 6, Jordan, Hockey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
select LISTAGG(name, '-'),
       Age, Nickname, FavSport
  from yourTable
group by Age, Nickname, FavSport
```

The above query will give you:

```
A-B, 5, Jordan, Hockey
A-B, 6, Jordan, Hockey
```

To solve it on the first output a simple where clause would do:

```
select name,
       Age, Nickname, FavSport
  from yourTable
 Where name = 'A'
```

Comment: Is there any "catch all" where I could use "*" instead of explicitly listing out the name of every other field I want to include in the output?

Comment: Since you have to group then up, no you can't. Also using a `*` is a bad practice. Always name your fields the database takes indexes benefits from it and you will avoid maintaining problems.